# Why might paramiko connect more slowly than openssh client?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm using paramiko to run some commands over ssh.  I notice that paramiko takes 2-3 seconds to open a connection, while the command line ssh client is almost instant.

Using some prints, I've found that the sticking point is Transport.auth_publickey (it is using a discovered ~/.ssh/id_dsa).  That's the same authentication method that command line ssh is using, so why might paramiko be running more slowly?

The code I'm using to connect is pretty simply:

```
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('myhostname', **{'username': 'root'})
```

Comment: It seems that paramiko is written in pure python. If this step is computationally intensive, it may be 50 times slower than an equivalent C function.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because the [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) operations needed both for the Diffie-Hellman key-exchange and the RSA public key authentication are orders of magnitude slower in a Python bytecode interpreter (as in pure Python Paramiko) compared to heavily optimized compiled native binary that OpenSSH uses.